# Delphi component hints hanging

Tags: delphi, hints

I have trouble with 3rd party Delphi component hints. Sometimes they don't disappear and they are just hanging on the screen. Is there a way to address hint created for specific component and hide it manually?

Generally it is possible to determine when it happens - for example when I hit a button with hint which opens another form. Then the hint does not hide until I close that form.

Thank you, Matěj

Comment: Are you showing this other form as modal form?

Comment: Yes I do. Sometimes it even happens with a 3rd party grid component with text fit hint (hint appears while hovering over shortened long text in cell)

Comment: Any luck with `Application.CancelHint;` or `Application.HideHint;`?

Comment: Use @Brian's suggestion just before showing your modal form, not after.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Unfortunately, it didn't work. There is even another situation when i press the button which switches to different page of PageControl and the hint wont disappear until I switch back to the Page with the button.

Comment: Create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you can. I can think if a few ways this could happen but an MCVE would get rid of the guesswork. Hiding hints is event driven so if you bypass them in some way it could lead to hanging hints.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have been discussing this issue with the component developer and he offered a solution that he would hide hints based on some timer, which should do the job, but it would be better to have direct control of Hints - i.e. hiding them all with some command. I'm affraid that I can't provide source of the components as they are not free.